# HTTP Error 406 utilizando componentes Rest Delphi com retorno XML

Tags: delphi, xml, rest

Estou tentando consultar uma NFS-e com os componentes REST no delphi XE7, nas consultas do tipo Json consegui normalmente, porem quando o retorno é do tipo XML ele da o erro 406, já tentei enviar o Accept e Content-Type no header porem tambem não resolveu, alguem já passou por esta situação? preciso fazer algum tratamento diferenciado quando o retorno é XML?

Segue o código:

```
  RESTRequest.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTClient.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTResponse.ResetToDefaults;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://nfps-e-hml.pmf.sc.gov.br/api/v1/consultas/notas/xml/126564/4554566';

  RESTClient.Authenticator := nil;

  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;

  RESTRequest.Execute;

  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Text := RESTResponse.Content;
```

Erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione um print do erro, 406 pode ser muito genérico pelo fato da `RESTClient` ser baseada na Indy.

Comment: Coloquei todo o retorno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes do `Execute` defina um `Accept` adequado ao arquivo que esta tentando acessar:

```
RESTRequest.Accept := 'text/xml';
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

Realize os teste e informe o resultado.

Comment: Funcionou kk, havia testado de tudo e não havia funcionado, muito obrigado :)

Answer (score -1):

Também pode funcionar

```
RESTRequest.Accept := 'application/json';
RESTRequest.Execute;
```